# How does sorting by multiple variables work in a proc report?

Tags: sas, proc-report

I  just don't get it. I have few numeric dates and have to sort my report by them(and do not display)
I need to sort by SUBJECT then DTN then STDTN then ENDTN;
Regular sas sorting:

```
proc sort;
by SUBJECT DTN STDTN ENDTN;
end;
```

does exactly what I need. but how to make it in poc report? When I use

```
define SUBJECT /order order=internal;
define DTN /order order=internal noprint;
define STDTN /order order=internal noprint;
define ENDTN /order order=internal noprint;
```

As I understand, It considers observations where ENDTN=0 as missing and doesn't add them to report. But why? They are not missing, they're=0. And then if I use `missing;` option it adds those observations where ENDTN=0 but they are at the end of subgrup and are not correctly sorted by DTN STDTN.  I tried to replace 0 with 1 to test it. But result looks similiar to result with `missing;` option. Can someone explain how it works and how can I get the desired result.

Comment: What does your `column` statement look like? The order in which `define` statements appear has nothing to do with the actual order of the report. Do you have any other order statements anywhere? I'm also not sure where this 'ENDTN=0 as missing' comes from because 0 is not a missing value, and missings get sorted *first*.

Comment: Yes, the reason was that the variables were in the wrong order in `column`  statement. didn't know it depends on that, thanks. Now it's sorted properly. But still only with `missing` option :) But it's good anyway.

Comment: @PBulls But another question appeared. After I made the changes and the code looks something like this:     `columns SUBJECT DTN STDTN ENDTN TERM_upcase .... TERM ;
 by TRT;
        define SUBJECT /order order=internal;
 define DTN /order order=internal noprint;
 define STDTN /order order=internal noprint;
 define ENDTN /order order=internal noprint;
 define TERM_upcase /order order=internal noprint;
 define TERM / group ;`
 Lines stopped grouping by TERM. What could be the reason, how is it related to the order of declaration of variables?

Comment: If by grouping you mean that the same values don't get printed on the next line, this happens in order of the `column` definition *including non-printed ones*. If you have the same term with different start and/or end date they will break the grouping.